# WooCommerce: Don't allow the user to refresh or redirect the page while payment completes

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, payment-gateway

How can this be implemented? In my country most of the E-Commerce websites have a notice which says "Please don't refresh the page while the payment completes" or something like that. Is this the standard practice around the world?

WooCommerce takes like 3-7 seconds for the payment to get completed. I don't want the user to refresh the page or redirect to another link while this happens. In case of a notice, which hook should I use to display a notice while the payment occurs? If there are better solutions than this which block any links the user clicks, please share. Thanks.